# Magento 2 Invalid template file

Tags: exception, magento-core, magento2.4.0, invalid-template

I am trying to override sales_order_create_index.xml to remove the custom payment method but getting this error

`1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Custom_Module:order/create/billing/method/info.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Sales' block's name: 'order_create_billing_form'`

**sales_order_create_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_create_billing_form">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Module::order/create/billing/method/info.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Template Path:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file name is `form.phtml` and you have set template name `info.phtml`. So either update your file name to `info.phtml` or update template name in xml file to `form.phtml` and clean cache once.

Comment: Let me know if it helps

Comment: Oops, I forgot to update that. Thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: You're welcome ;-)